# Form session not working when multiple users use it

Tags: php, forms, session, sessionid

i need an help from you all.

i had created an form using PHP. it's a school application registration form. it has one page only.

i need to generate registration number(session id used as registration number here) for everyone who opens the form.

instead of creating a session i have used ID for all. that is when some one submits the form, it checks the DB and if the registration number is there, it will increment one value and add the current form to DB.

my code here

```
<td>Application No : <input type="hidden" name="disablusr_dummyid" autocomplete="off" style="background:#f0efed;" value="00<?php
        include('config.php');
        $q="select MAX(auto_gen_id) from application_form";
        $result=mysql_query($q);
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $max_val=$data[0];
        echo $max_val+1;
        ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="applicant_id" autocomplete="off" value="00<?php
         include('config.php');
        $wer = "select MAX(auto_gen_id) from application_form";
        $resultgh = mysql_query($wer);
        $dates = mysql_fetch_array($resultgh);
        $erfdqwe = $dates[0];           
        echo $erfdqwe+1;
  ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="txt_applicant_id" style="display:none;" autocomplete="off" value="<?php
         include('config.php');
        $werqw = "select MAX(auto_gen_id) from application_form";
        $resultghasw = mysql_query($werqw);
        $dataqsax = mysql_fetch_array($resultghasw);
        $erfdqweqti = $dataqsax[0];         
        echo $erfdqweqti+1;
    ?>" /></td>
```

but what is happening is when multiple users are using the form same session ID is generated and only one user is able to save the form and it reflects in DB. other forms are being not submitted and not added to DB.

help me in this error..  thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use auto-increment id in mysql for registration ID ?

Comment: Why dont you just generate id AFTER submitting...

Comment: Where is the session?

Comment: Why are you including the same file multiple times. Why are you executing the same query multiple times. And I don't see and session used here.

Comment: So u are using user input to start a session? This is very vulnerable to session hijacking then. No wonder this does not work for multiple users because when user one and two open the form at the same time, they get the same seed.

Comment: I tried auto-increment already.. but id is the same. @ codingAnt

Comment: generating after submitting is correct option. but we need to show the generated register number in top of the form. so the user will keep the note of it. @ Toumash

Comment: @nabil & bansi - we didnt use session here. instead we use the page id for generating the register number'

Comment: But that is not ok. As I said if multiple user open the page without submitting they all have the same last max id. U should only calculate the ID on submit, not before

Comment: your correct @DarkBee.. the same thing happens in my case.. both of them got same ID while registering..  we didnt think about session hijacking as we are doing it for a school. it is not as that much important.

Comment: @Toumash i used your help & changed my form. the idea works fine that is generating the id after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is not the use the hidden fields for the IDs :
At this moment u have something like this :

`"INSERT INTO (id, ..., ...) VALUES('".addslashes($_POST['applicant_id']."', ...)`

You should refactor your logic to calculate the id afterwards meaning that u drop the hidden fields and do this :

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $wer = "select MAX(auto_gen_id) from application_form";
    $resultgh = mysql_query($wer);
    $dates = mysql_fetch_array($resultgh);
    $erfdqwe = $dates[0];           
    $new_applicant_id = $erfdqwe+1;           
   }
```

And then use the `$new_applicant_id` into the INSERT sql.
On a sidenote your code is vulnerable for SQL injection and is using outdated functions.
You should try to move to `mysqli` or `PDO` and preferable use  `prepared statements`

Comment: i had removed all session targets and changed to get the registration Id from the session submit field. like i'm generating the id while submitting the form.